# difference when using & and not using &

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Hi,
    I was using like

```
$formCheckbox = $form->addElement('radio',...);
$formCheckbox->setChecked(true);
```

this was working on windows properly but was not on linux i.e it was not checking the radio button.

so i changed it like

```
$formCheckbox = **&**$form->addElement('radio',...);
$formCheckbox->setChecked(true);
```

so i just used & while creating the element. I just wanted to know how does it make a difference.  I am using HTML quick forms.

Comment: when i use & it works on linux or else it wont work. Thats the main question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case there is not much of a difference, because php handles objects internally as pointers..

but as long as you do not know what & stands for, don't use it..

a short introduction to pointer:

```
$a = 10; 
$b = &$a; 
$b = 20; 
echo $a; -> 20 

$a = 10; 
$b = $a; 
$b = 20; 
echo $a; -> 10
```

so with & you only reference to another variable, instead of creating a new one

Comment: when i use & it works on linux or else it wont work. Thats the main question here

Answer (score 1):

It is passing the variable as a reference, so that the changes are maintained always.

Check this http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php